# Listening for the control key in my view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a tool that only runs when the Ctrl key is pressed. I'm listening for it in this function in my view model.

```
private ImageManipulationTool WheelTool
{
    get
    {
        bool IsControlPressed = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl);

        if (CurrentTool == loupeTool && IsControlPressed)
        {
            return loupeRadiusTool;
        }
        else if (CurrentTool == zoomTool || IsControlPressed)
        {
            return zoomTool;
        }

        // default wheel tool
        return sliceTool;
    }
}
```

But this isn't really MVVM-correct. The keyboard is basically an element of the view. And now my code isn't testable because, as a view model, I'm pretty sure that even simulating key events won't work because there's no target.

So I know the answer is input bindings on the window. However, the solutions I've seen don't seem to cover my cases:

1. I'm using just the control key, and it doesn't seem like you're allowed to bind to a modifier key without a "normal" key
2. I need to know if the key is pressed, but the keybindings seem to only listen for key down.
3. Less important, I'd like the key binding to be in the file for my `UserControl` rather than all the way up in the `MainWindow`. But it seems like `Window.InputBindings` is where these need to go.

How can I get all of this to work?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

One possiblity is to use the events `PreviewKeyDown` and `PreviewKeyUp` in your UserControl. From there you can check the keystates and set a property in your viewmodel.

```
           private void UserControl_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                    if (sender == null)
                            return;

                    if(sender is YourUserControl uc && uc.DataContext is YourViewModel vm)
                    {
                            if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl || e.Key == Key.RightCtrl)
                                    vm.IsCtrlKeyPressed = true;
                    }
            }
```

Implement the `PreviewKeyUp` event and you are ready to use the IsCtrlKeyPressed-Property without breaking the MVVM pattern.

Edit: Seems like you don't need to check `e.KeyStates` since you are on the `KeyDown/Up` Event anyways. But you can use `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` if you want to be sure.

Comment: This seems like a great idea, but I've attached `KeyDown="Image_KeyDown"` (also key up, also preview of both) to the `Image` control (and also tried on the parent `UserControl`) but the event handler isn't being raised. I've tried clicking around the screen to move focus, with no help.

Comment: Maybe your control does not have the Keyboard focus. Try to attach to `MouseUp`-event on your UserControl an set the Keyboardfocus to the Usercontrol: `Keyboard.Focus(sender as UserControl);`